# Boostrap tabbable tab-pane not working

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, tabpanel

In .aspx page I have 2 tabs: Acct and HR.

In code behind I have these conditions:

- If user is **Acct** then display only Acct tab (hide HR tab and navigation)
- Else If user is **HR** then display only Hr tab (hide Acct tab and navigation)
- Else (if user is not Acct and Hr) then display both of tabs and navigation menus (I want the **Acct** will be the `active` one first)

So case #1 and case #2 are working properly.

But case #3 (which need to show both of tabs and navigation and everything), I have problems: The navigation (`li`) is working fine (when I click on it, it does display proper CSS), but the tab (content) always show the **Acct** tab, not changing to **HR** tab when I lick to HR `li`

Here are the pictures of the case #3, so in page_load() code I set it displays the Acct tab first:
[image]

When I switch to HR tab, the navigation menu is changed but the content tab stays the same:

[image]

And vice versa, if I set **HR** is the `active` one then when I switch to **Acct** it will NOT show Acct tab content, keep displaying HR's tab contents

Here are markup codes and C# codes:

```
<div class="tabbable tabbable-custom">
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs" style="margin-bottom: 0px">
                    <li style="width: 50%" id="liAcct" runat="server"><a class="no-margin" href="#tabAcct" data-toggle="tab">
                        <h3 class="text-center no-margin bold text-success">ACCT</h3>
                    </a></li>
                    <li style="width: 50%" id="liHR" runat="server"><a class="no-margin" href="#tabHR" data-toggle="tab">
                        <h3 class="text-center no-margin bold text-primary" style="margin-left: 20px !important">HR</h3>
                    </a></li>
                </ul>

                <div class="tab-content" style="border: 1px solid #ddd; border-top: none; padding: 5px">

                    <!-- BEGIN ACCT TAB -->
                    <div class="tab-pane" id="tabAcct" runat="server">

                        <asp:Panel ID="panelAcct" runat="server">
                            <h1>This is Acct content</h1>
                        </asp:Panel>

                    </div>
                    <!-- END TAB -->

                    <!-- BEGIN HR TAB -->
                    <div class="tab-pane" id="tabHR" runat="server">

                        <asp:Panel ID="panelHR" runat="server">
                            <h1>This is HR content</h1>
                        </asp:Panel>

                    </div>
                    <!-- END TAB -->

                </div>
            </div>
```

In page_load():

```
if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                Page.Title = "Page";
                string managerEmail = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name.ToLower();
                if (requestDAL.GetManagerLevel_byEmail(managerEmail) <= 1)
                {
                    // Shows HR tab
                    liHR.Attributes["class"] = "active";
                    tabHR.Attributes["class"] = "tab-pane active";

                    // Hide Acct tab
                    liAcct.Visible = false;
                    liAcct.Visible = false;
                    panelAcct.Visible = false;

                }
                else if (requestDAL.GetManagerLevel_byEmail(managerEmail) == 2)
                {
                    // Shows ACCT tab
                    liAcct.Attributes["class"] = "active";
                    tabAcct.Attributes["class"] = "tab-pane active";

                    // Hide HR tab
                    liHR.Visible = false;
                    liHR.Visible = false;
                    panelHR.Visible = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    liAcct.Attributes["class"] = "active";
                    tabAcct.Attributes["class"] = "tab-pane active";

                }

            }
```

Comment: What happens when you active **HR** by default? Does the `nav li` works for **Acct**?

Comment: @Shaharyar same thing, if I activate HR first then `nav li` works for Acct but the tab content of Acct is not showed, only HR content being displayed.

Comment: Is there any error in your browser's console?

Comment: @Shaharyar No error before and after I click.

Comment: I tried your code in jsfiddle and it works very fine there. Try replacing `href` with `data-target` and check again.

Comment: @Shaharyar just changed, not working either!

Comment: @Shaharyar one thing I noticed in browser console is that: the ID is changed, it became something like `ContentPlaceHolder1_tabAcct` instead of tabAcct, maybe that why the `href` is not working?

Comment: Ah forgot that.. Asp changes the IDs. Its a quick fix, just use ClientId.

Comment: @Shaharyar Where and how to use `ClientID`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asp.net changes all serverside controls IDs at client side. You just need to use [ClientID](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientid%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to get the correct markup IDs:

```
<a class="no-margin" href="#<%= tabAcct.ClientID %>" data-toggle="tab">

<a class="no-margin" href="#<%= tabHR.ClientID %>" data-toggle="tab">
```

Comment: I have an additional small-question: When I click on the navigation menu/header, why doesn't the url show the hash (ex: #tabAcct or #tabHR), because I want to know what tab is currently active so that I can retrieve it when a `postback event` orrcuring